# Ajax uploader Error 500

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a Ajax uploader on my page. It worked fine since yesterday. 
Now I get an Error 500. In console it says

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

and refers to my upload script:

```
  <?php
// A list of permitted file extensions
$allowed = array('html','htm');

function save_table_to_json ( $in_file, $out_file ) {
    $html = file_get_contents( $in_file );
    file_put_contents( $out_file, convert_table_to_json( $html ) );
}

function convert_table_to_json ( $html ) {
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadHTML( $html );

$xpath = new DomXPath($document);
$tables = $xpath->query("//*[contains(@class, 'mon_list')]");
$tableDom = new DomDocument();
$tableDom->appendChild($tableDom->importNode($tables->item(0), true));

$obj = [];
$jsonObj = [];
$th = $tableDom->getElementsByTagName('th');
$td = $tableDom->getElementsByTagName('td');
$thNum = $th->length;
$arrLength = $td->length;
$rowIx = 0;

for ( $i = 0 ; $i < $arrLength ; $i++){
    $head = $th->item( $i%$thNum )->textContent;
    $content = $td->item( $i )->textContent;
    $obj[ $head ] = $content;
    if( ($i+1) % $thNum === 0){ 
        $jsonObj[++$rowIx] = $obj;
        $obj = [];
    }
}

    return json_encode([ "Values" => $jsonObj ]);
}


if(isset($_FILES['upl']) && $_FILES['upl']['error'] == 0){

    $extension = pathinfo($_FILES['upl']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    if(!in_array(strtolower($extension), $allowed)){
        echo '{"status":"error1"}';
        exit;
    }

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upl']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['upl']['name'])){
        save_table_to_json( 'heute_S.htm', 'heute_S.json' );
        save_table_to_json( 'heute_L.htm', 'heute_L.json' );
        save_table_to_json( 'morgen_S.htm', 'morgen_S.json' );
        save_table_to_json( 'morgen_L.htm', 'morgen_L.json' );
        echo '{"status":"success1"}';
    }else{
    echo '{"status":"error"}';
    exit;
}
}
```

I didn´t change anything on server. In server legit only says there was a error 500.

But how can I fix that ?

---

Edit:

In Log it says:

> [Wed Dec 02 17:31:26.625826 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 11680] [client IP]
>   mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Empty string
>   supplied as input in /upload.php on line 12, referer: /

The second:

> [Wed Dec 02 17:31:26.625830 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 11680] [client IP]
>   mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Catchable fatal error:  Argument 1 passed to
>   DOMDocument::importNode() must be an instance of DOMNode, null given,
>   called in /upload.php on line 7 and defined in /upload.php on line 17,
>   referer: /

Comment: what have you before the error?

Comment: it worked fine with the same script no changes.

Comment: and where is your ajax uploader code? we would see that too.

Comment: these are the codes I use template. Minot familiar with Ajax.

Comment: The error 500 is caused by the server, not the client. You must to share your server code, not the javascript. you must to check your error log in the apache server and then you will know what happens automatically

Answer (score 1):

Check your webserver error logs. Depending on webserver, should be in either /var/log/apache or /var/log/nginx.

Those will give you information about what's actually going wrong, and you should be able to resolve it easily enough from there.

Comment: I agree to @rlweb, for 500 error codes the server error log file is the most informative.

Comment: The apache2 directory is empty. The nginx does not exist

Comment: In Plesk under the gab log It on only says 2015-12-02 09:36:20
Error
IP
500
POST /upload.php HTTP/1.1
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_1) AppleWebKit/601.2.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0.1 Safari/601.2.7
372
Apache-SSL

Comment: Try looking in /var/log/httpd. If you're on a specific subdomain, can be /var/www/vhosts/DOMAIN/statistics/logs/error_log.

Comment: @rlweb I updated the code and the Log data but what is the Problem ? It worked fine yesterday and now not

Comment: $tables = $xpath->query("//*[contains(@class, 'mon_list')]"); is returning null, which is most likely your issue. I'm not very familiar with the DOMDocument class, but it would probably be a good idea to do perform some tests before you pass it along.

I'd try doing a var_dump on xpath first, and if that gives null, go backwards in your code.